# Find the sum of all $x$ such that $y = 2 - \frac{9}{x+1}$ has an integer solution $(x, y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

> Find the sum of all $x$ such that $y = 2 - \frac{9}{x + 1}$ has an integer solution $(x, y)$

I made $x$ the subject of the formula, i.e., wrote $$x = \left(\frac{9}{2 - y}\right) - 1 .$$ I don't know what to do after that. I need the full solution. Thanks.

Comment: There is something wrong with your transformation. $(9,0)$ satisfies the original equation, but not your transformed equation.

Comment: The formatting confuses me. So I should simply add x and -x?
Then,
x + (-x) = 9/(2-y) - 1 + (-9/(2-y) + 1)
0 = 9/(2-y) - 1 - 9/(2-y) + 1
0 = 0
I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Rearranging gives $\frac{9}{x} = 1 - y$. In particular, for any solution $(x, y)$, $\frac{9}{x}$ is an integer, so (1) if $x$ is a solution, so is $-x$, and (2) there are only finitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that the equation is equivalent to
$$
(2-y)(x+1)=9
$$

Comment: Hold on, maybe you're reading the question all wrong. y is on the left side of the equation, alone. On the right side, there are two terms. 2 and -9/(x+1). (x+1) is the denominator of -9.

So the question is: 
x and y are integers such that y = 2 - 9/(x+1). Find the sum of all possible values of x.

Comment: The equation in the question reads $$y=2-\left(\frac9x+1\right)$$ If you want $$y=2-\frac9{x+1}$$ then you need to edit the question and title, or ask a new question if there are more people who answer this one.

Comment: Okay I've done that. But can you answer it? I really need the solution